# How to make elements added in JavaScript react to onclick like ones added in HTML?

Tags: javascript

I have an input that allows me to add new `<p>` elements using java script, I also have `<p>` elements added in html. I have very simple onclick function, and it works just fine on elements added in html, but newly added elements ignore it.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input")
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick = function () { 
   var p = document.createElement("p");
   p.innerHTML = input.value ;  
   document.body.appendChild(p);
   p.id="p";}

function clik(elem) 
{
      elem.style.color = "green";   
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="input"></input>
  <button type="button" id="button"> add </button>
  <p class="p" type="button" id="p" onclick="clik(this)"> added in html </p>
  <p class="p" type="button" id="p" onclick="clik(this)"> added in html </p>
  <p class="p" type="button" id="p" onclick="clik(this)"> added in html </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried:

```
   button.onclick = function () { 
   var p = document.createElement("p");
   p.innerHTML = input.value ;  
   document.body.appendChild(p);
   p.id="p";
   p.onclick=clik(p);}
```

but then it's always green, and I want to make it green onclick.

Comment: id's neeeds to be unique, one of the kind, no way around it! it is an id!

Comment: One quick thing that's worth noting, is that you are duplicating your id. id's are unique identifiers. In your case, the id should be a class instead.

Answer (score 1):

You don't set the event click handler on your new item. You could do it like this:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input")
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick = function () { 
   var p = document.createElement("p");
   p.innerHTML = input.value ;  
   p.setAttribute('onclick','clik(this);'); // Here I set the new onclick handler
   document.body.appendChild(p);

}

function clik(elem) 
{
      elem.style.color = "green";   
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="input"></input>
  <button type="button" id="button"> add </button>
  <p class="p" type="button" id="p" onclick="clik(this)"> added in html </p>
  <p class="p" type="button" id="p" onclick="clik(this)"> added in html </p>
  <p class="p" type="button" id="p" onclick="clik(this)"> added in html </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also don't set the same id for multiple elements. I removed that code. The rest is the same :)

Answer (score 0):

It is always green because you are calling the clik function and passing the response to onclick. You need to assign the function to onclick. Additionally when you pass a function to onclick, you receive an event as param and you can use `event.target` to get the element. See code below:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input")
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick = function () { 
   var p = document.createElement("p");
   p.innerHTML = input.value ; 
   p.onclick=clik; 
   document.body.appendChild(p);
   p.id="p";}

function clik(event) 
{
      const el = event.target || event;
      el.style.color = "green";   
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="input"></input>
  <button type="button" id="button"> add </button>
  <p class="p" type="button" id="p" onclick="clik(this)"> added in html </p>
  <p class="p" type="button" id="p" onclick="clik(this)"> added in html </p>
  <p class="p" type="button" id="p" onclick="clik(this)"> added in html </p>
  </body>
</html>
```